# Segmentation fault when pushing POD to queue

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, queue, valgrind

I have encountered a very weird issue with some code I have been writing; a segmentation fault is occurring in `std::deque::emplace_back` when pushing a struct:

```
struct ChunkMeshTask {
    union {
        ChunkID                       id;  //< ui64
        ChunkRectilinearWorldPosition pos; //< i24, i16, i24
    };
    Chunk*  chunk;
};
```

to a queue stored as a member of the same class as the method in which the push is performed:

```
namespace h {
    using Sender = const void*;
}

namespace hvox {
    class ChunkGrid {
        ...
    public:
        void handleBlockChange(Sender sender, BlockChangeEvent event);
        ...
    protected:
        std::queue<ChunkMeshTask> m_meshTasks; // = std::queue<ChunkMeshTask>(); was tried as a sanity check.
        ...
    };
}

void hvox::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange(h::Sender sender, BlockChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO(Matthew): We really shouldn't be submitting a mesh task for each block change...
    //                We want AT MOST one mesh task per chunk on the queue at any given time regardless of number of blocks changed.
    m_meshTasks.push(ChunkMeshTask{
        { event.chunkPos },
        (Chunk*)sender
    });
}
```

This segmentation fault doesn't occur in MSVC, but does in GCC and Clang, debugging with GDB shows that all values (including the pointer `sender`) are valid at the call of `hvox::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange`.

`hvox::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange` is called from an event system, that in this particular case is invoking a delegate that wraps the function. I mention this as to try to dig deeper I ran my program through valgrind. In addition to fixing various unrelated bugs, it has yielded two distinct errors that seem to be related but that I cannot get an understanding of with respect to the problem I'm facing:

```
==7788== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7788==    at 0x4249F9: void std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> >::emplace_back<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (deque.tcc:158)
==7788==    by 0x423FB5: std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> >::push_back(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (stl_deque.h:1533)
==7788==    by 0x4236DD: std::queue<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> > >::push(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (stl_queue.h:248)
==7788==    by 0x422BB2: hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange(void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (ChunkGrid.cpp:52)
==7788==    by 0x424E3C: void hemlock::Delegate<void, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::executeWithObject<hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid, void>(void const*, void (hemlock::TypelessMember::*)(), void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Delegate.hpp:167)
==7788==    by 0x425C09: hemlock::Delegate<void, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::operator()(void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) const (Delegate.hpp:112)
==7788==    by 0x424F02: void hemlock::executeDelegate<void, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>(stx::basic_any<5ul>, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:303)
==7788==    by 0x4222C4: hemlock::Event<hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::trigger(hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:130)
==7788==    by 0x42218D: hemlock::Event<hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::operator()(hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:135)
==7788==    by 0x422020: hemlock::voxel::Chunk::setBlock(hemlock::voxel::BlockChunkPosition, hemlock::voxel::Block) (Chunk.cpp:25)
==7788==    by 0x40B138: ChunkGenerator::runGenTask(hemlock::voxel::ChunkGenTask, unsigned short) (ChunkGenerator.cpp:51)
==7788==    by 0x422A49: hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid::update() (ChunkGrid.cpp:35)
==7788==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7788==    at 0x424EB8: void hemlock::executeDelegate<void, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>(stx::basic_any<5ul>, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:299)
```

This error implies there's something uninitialised in `hemlock::executeDelegate<void, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>` but again, using GDB I have verified that `delegate` (stored in a 5-byte-wide `std::any`), the pointer `sender` and the struct in `parameters` are all valid here. The function looks like:

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename ...Parameters>
ReturnType executeDelegate(DelegateAny callback, Sender sender, Parameters... parameters) {
    using MyDelegate = Delegate<ReturnType, Sender, Parameters...>;
    MyDelegate delegate = delegateAnyCast<MyDelegate>(callback); // delegateAnyCast is just a wrapper of std::any_cast specifically for an internal 5-byte wide stack storage in std::any.

    return delegate(sender, parameters...);
}
```

Using GDB again, everything is valid inside the delegate, and the wrapped function is called with the expected parameters.

The last error valgrind yields before the seg fault is:

```
==7788== Invalid write of size 8
==7788==    at 0x4260C5: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>::construct<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask*, hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (new_allocator.h:120)
==7788==    by 0x4257EC: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> >::construct<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>(std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>&, hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask*, hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==7788==    by 0x4249E8: void std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> >::emplace_back<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask>(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (deque.tcc:155)
==7788==    by 0x423FB5: std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> >::push_back(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (stl_deque.h:1533)
==7788==    by 0x4236DD: std::queue<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::deque<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask, std::allocator<hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask> > >::push(hemlock::voxel::ChunkMeshTask&&) (stl_queue.h:248)
==7788==    by 0x422BB2: hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange(void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (ChunkGrid.cpp:52)
==7788==    by 0x424E3C: void hemlock::Delegate<void, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::executeWithObject<hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid, void>(void const*, void (hemlock::TypelessMember::*)(), void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Delegate.hpp:167)
==7788==    by 0x425C09: hemlock::Delegate<void, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::operator()(void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) const (Delegate.hpp:112)
==7788==    by 0x424F02: void hemlock::executeDelegate<void, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>(stx::basic_any<5ul>, void const*, hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:303)
==7788==    by 0x4222C4: hemlock::Event<hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::trigger(hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:130)
==7788==    by 0x42218D: hemlock::Event<hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent>::operator()(hemlock::voxel::BlockChangeEvent) (Event.hpp:135)
==7788==    by 0x422020: hemlock::voxel::Chunk::setBlock(hemlock::voxel::BlockChunkPosition, hemlock::voxel::Block) (Chunk.cpp:25)
==7788==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Which I cannot parse in this case at all, it's something to do with an invalid pointer, but on my end there are no pointers involved except for the `hvox::Chunk` pointer, which I have confirmed to be valid using GDB on push.

The seg fault occurs inside `deque.tcc` at the first line of `std::deque::emplace_back`:

```
if (this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_cur != this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_last - 1) { ... }
```

specifically the iterator `this->_M_impl._M_finish` appears to be invalid.

This is all single-threaded, so nothing else is happening to the queue to cause iterators to invalidate (though I assume internal iterators are always valid?).

### Progress Report #1

It has been pointed out that the `this` pointer of `hvox::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange` could be invalid after going through the event system, this has turned out to be the case. That said the object pointer is valid until after leaving the delegate and entering the wrapped function of the delegate. The exit point being:

```
    // Execution routine for member functions (const or not).
    template<typename SpecificClass, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<SpecificClass>::value>::type>
    static ReturnType executeWithObject(GenericObject object, GenericMemberFunction function, Parameters... parameters) {
        MemberFunction<SpecificClass> operation = (MemberFunction<SpecificClass>)function;
        SpecificClass*                   target = (SpecificClass*)object;

        return (target->*operation)(parameters...);
    }
```

### Progress Report #2

After doing as much digging as I can, it does seem like this *should* be valid, and indeed in other similar scenarios the event/delegate system executes correctly. I have even tried allocating the `hvox::ChunkGrid` object to the heap to see if it was indeed a scope issue, to no avail - the object definitely still exists, it's just not being assigned to the `this` pointer.

Comment: is `this` valid when executing `hemlock::voxel::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange`? You mentioned it is an event kicking this off, are you calling an event on an object (`ChunkGrid`) that hasn't been created yet (potentially, [static initialization order](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order))

Comment: Well, you cast some object to pointer (bad) and that something is a local variable that goes immediately out of scope (bad). Not clear what you're intending to do.

Comment: You can't determine that objects are valid through inspection. You can only separate the definitely bad from the possibly good.

Comment: @Ics Up to the delegate executing the wrapped method. I'm not sure why it's failing - it hasn't in any other circumstance, both with MSVC or GCC/Clang. I'll add the function that seems to be failing to the post.

Comment: @juanchopanza Where are you referring to? I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean.

Comment: This: `(Chunk*)sender`

Comment: That pointer is valid @juanchopanza; it is the same as the this pointer of the `hvox::Chunk` object that triggered the event. Edit: More importantly, i is also still valid in that its contents have not been deleted.

Comment: @MatthewMarshall Too bad you didn't post enough code to show that.

Comment: Apologies @juanchopanza I didn't want to bog down the post. I use the event/delegate systems in multiple places and in other projects fine. After the results of valgrind/gdb I thought it was something I could leave out.

Comment: @MatthewMarshall  Thanks. You added some crucial info, the definition of `h::Sender`. That addresses my previous comments. The goal is to post a [mcve].

Comment: @lcs I explored the suggestion of static initialisation order being the problem, but the `hvox::ChunkGrid` object is established before `hvox::ChunkGrid::handleBlockChange` is called for sure. I'm finding that the object pointer is valid until I use it to call a function on - at which point it is not being used to assign the `this` pointer. I added the code in my post where this occurs.

Comment: @juanchopanza would it be appropriate to make a new question with better details, more code and also a focus on what has turned out to be the actual problem (which isn't what this question initially was)?